# Sugar ORM No such table exeption

Tags: android, sqlite, orm

Использую Sugar ORM версии 1.4, на версиях Андроид ниже 5 всё работает отлично, но выше 5 версии выходит эта ошибка.

Прошу помочь.

Error: `android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: AUDIO (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM AUDIO`

proguard-rules.pro

```
-keep class me.lobanov.mp3downloadsfree.models.** { *; }
```

My model class:

```
package me.lobanov.mp3downloadsfree.models;

import com.orm.SugarRecord;

import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;
import lombok.ToString;

@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
public class Audio extends SugarRecord {
    private long aud_id;
    private String aud_artist;
    private String aud_title;
    private String aud_url;
    private long aud_duration;

    public Audio() {
    }

    public Audio(long aud_id, String aud_artist, String aud_title, String aud_url, long aud_duration){
        this.aud_id = aud_id;
        this.aud_artist = aud_artist;
        this.aud_title = aud_title;
        this.aud_url = aud_url;
        this.aud_duration = aud_duration;
    }
}
```

My application class:

```
public class App extends SugarApp {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
    }
}
```

My manifest:

```
<meta-data android:name="DATABASE" android:value="mp3downloadsfree.db" />
        <meta-data android:name="VERSION" android:value="5" />
        <meta-data android:name="QUERY_LOG" android:value="true" />
        <meta-data android:name="DOMAIN_PACKAGE_NAME" android:value="me.lobanov.mp3downloadsfree.models" />
```

Comment: Когда накатываете приложение, предыдущий билд удалили?

Comment: @АндроидАндроид , удалял несколько раз, тестировал на другом эмуляторе,ничего не помогло, пишет,что нет такой таблицы и всё

Comment: В манифесте у application прописали? android:name="com.orm.SugarApp" И еще приложите код класса, где работаете с базой

Comment: @АндроидАндроид, зачем в манифеесте это нужно если я наследуюсь от SugarApp
А использую я одну строчку
List<Audio> audios = Audio.listAll(Audio.class); на андроиде ниже 5ой версии всё работает

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы sugarORM создал таблицы надо изменить структуру БД в данном случае ваш класс Audio и версию в AndroidManifest.xml Решение для Вас такое:

- Добавьте в Audio новое поле int tester

> ```
> public class Audio extends SugarRecord {
>
>     private long aud_id;
>     private String aud_artist;
>     private String aud_title;
>     private String aud_url;
>     private long aud_duration;
>     private int tester;
>
>     public Audio() {
>     }
>
>     public Audio(long aud_id, String aud_artist, String aud_title, String aud_url, long aud_duration, int tester){
>         this.aud_id = aud_id;
>         this.aud_artist = aud_artist;
>         this.aud_title = aud_title;
>         this.aud_url = aud_url;
>         this.aud_duration = aud_duration;
>         this.tester= tester;
>     }
> }
> ```

- Измените версию на +1 `<meta-data android:name="VERSION" android:value="6" />`
- Запустите приложение (!) должно заработать
- Удалите из Audio int tester
- Измените версию на +1 `<meta-data android:name="VERSION" android:value="7" />`
- Запустите приложение

Answer (score 0):

Откопал на просторах [интернета](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31428499/2667883)

```
  -keep public me.lobanov.mp3downloadsfree.** extends SugarApp{*;}
```

Надеюсь, поможет.

Comment: не помогло, та же ошибка